# Determination detection of direction with 2 optic sensors which are on opposite sides of disc

Tags: sensor, optics, rpm

I would like to ask you is it possible to detect the direction of rotation with 2 optic sensors which are on opposite sides of disc? In the disc is small hole, when the part with hole goes through the optic sensor the signal from optic sensor is "1" otherwise is signal "0". I am thinking about method store order of 4 values (10,00,01,00) but it seems that it will not work.

Thanks in advance

[image: Optic sensors]

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have problems due to non-overlapping pulses which will make it impossible to tell which direction you are running.
To understand why your proposal won't work consider what happens when the wheel stops with a slot in one of the sensors. No matter which way you resume motion - forward or reverse - the output waveforms will be the same.

Normally this is done using quadrature encoder. There are two outputs which are 90° out of phase. (90° = quarter of a turn, hence quadrature.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKlhW9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. 2-bit rotary encoder waveforms.*

The program logic is very simple.

- Track the current state of 'A'. If the state changes to 'high' then:
- Look at input 'B'. If 'B' is low then count up. If 'B' is high then count down.

[image: Encoder]

*Figure 2. A simplifed encoder layout. A and B photo-sensors looking at or through the encoder disc will produce the waveforms of Figure 1. Artwork mine.*

Comment: Thank you very much for reply, it is very interesting.

Comment: Good. Don't forget to upvote useful answers and to accept one (after you've given enough time for others to answer) so that the system knows your question has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

It won’t work as you show it as you have no way see any other phase than 180 degrees. You can only detect rotational speed.

Instead, place the sensors near each other, then detect the relative periods between the pulses. If they are close enough that their edges actually overlap (like in quadurature) then you can detect both speed and direction in less than one rotation.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I expected similiar this solution, I will try it. Thanks